# Resize image responsive - have a div and inside I have dynamics images

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, image-resizing, dimensions

I have a div with 1184x308px and inside I have dynamics images logo (vertical and horizontal). How can I do to the image fill the div without stretch?

Comment: [Please read this about how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If your image is not big enough to fill the space as it seems you want then you cannot just simply have css styles with `width: 100% height: auto;` without stretching it. One option you could use to serve the right image at the right screen size is using `srcset` but it is not too well supported and you will probably want to use [picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill)

To use srcset on it's own you would use this:

```
<img src="small.jpg" srcset="medium.jpg 1000w, large.jpg 2000w" alt="dynamics">
```

It can be a bit tricky but a quick google on srcset should help you out or [this is good info](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/) on it.